# Firebase - Indexing Data Two Levels Deep

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase data structure that looks like:

```
-messages
    -myFirstUsername
        -5-2-16 04:02:23 AM
            -message: 'messageOne',
            -direction: 'outgoing'
        -5-3-16 04:07:23 AM
            -message: 'messageTwo',
            -direction: 'outgoing'
    -mySecondUsername
        -5-4-16 04:02:23 AM
            -message: 'messageOne',
            -direction: 'outgoing'
        -5-5-16 04:02:23 AM
            -message: 'messageTwo',
            -direction: 'incoming'
```

I would like to index all data using the `message` and `direction` nested child keys.  Since the username keys under the `messages` object are dynamic, I'll need to set up my index on the `messages` object itself.

Will the following rule set up indices two levels deep?

```
{
  "rules": {
    "messages": {
      ".indexOn": ["message", "direction"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: See Mathew's answer on how to add indexes to `/messages/$userId/$messageId`. But I'm not sure it'll solve your use-case. How are you looking to query the data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify dynamic .indexOn like this:

```
{
    "rules" : {
        "messages" : {
            "$userId": {
                ".indexOn" : ["message", "direction"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't seem to find it in the new docs, but here's the old docs description: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/api/rule/path.html

Comment: On the new website, the documentation for `.indexOn` is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/#section-defining-indexes).

Comment: Right, but surprisingly it doesn't talk about $location though it alludes to something above when the $uid.

Comment: You are a Firebase answer machine today